# Can "this" be used in place of a selector? ...in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm learning JavaScript and JQuery, and trying to wrap my head around "this." Is

```
$("p").click(function(){ $("p").slideUp('slow');});
```

functionally, the same as

```
$("p").click(function(){ $(this).slideUp('slow');});
```

?

I'm sure there are more clever ways to use "this", but if I'm right that it is functionally the same, then I know I have a little bit better understanding.

Comment: in first case: by click on _any_ **p** tag, slideUp **all** _p_ tags, in second:  by click on _any_ **p** tag, slideUp **only target** p tag

Comment: So, I was totally wrong! It makes so much sense, now!

Comment: The question was down voted? It was an honest question. How can I improve it?

Comment: methinks downvoted because it seems duplicate: you can see in _Related_ questions in sidebar and possibly you can find answer before asking

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that, as a beginner, I hardly have the vocabulary down, so, having read through the related/similar questions, I could see how they applied, but didn't give the kind of clarity I needed. Obviously, Stack Overflow isn't the place for, "I think I'm in the ballpark, but I need some reassurance" kind of questions. I shall probably come back once I have learned more from other resources. See you all in six months! ...if not sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" in javascript refers to the context of a function call.  The value of "this" depends on how the caller invoked the method.  In the case of jQuery, when it invokes an event handler, it sets "this" to the DOM element that is the target of the event.

$(this) wraps this DOM element in a jQuery object so that you can use jQuery methods against it.

$("p") selects all paragraph elements in your DOM.

$(this) selects only the element that was the target of the click event.

$("p").slideUp() will affect all paragraph elements on the page.

$(this).slideUp() will only affect a single element that was the target of the click event.